# Is it a good idea to rename the "index.php" in "wp-admin" folder to avoid being hacked?

Tags: hacked

My wordpress has been hacked for 2 or 3 times. How can I increase its security? Is it a good way to rename the `index.php` in `wp-admin` directory?

Comment: Security by obscurity is a joke...

Answer (score 7):

Renaming files will not make your blog more secure. Obscurity, hiding trivial information, is not a real security concept.

The `index.php` is safe. Make sure the [file permissions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress#File_Permissions) are set correctly, and try to find the real security hole you had.

Comment: All Files' permissions are 644, but hackers can change my wp admin password as easy as a pie :). Also I changed the .htaccess file to make my blog safer. however, I think the problem is related to wp security.

Comment: No, hackers cannot just change your admin password – unless you are allowing this. WordPress wouldn’t be what it is if that were possible.

Comment: If hackers can change your admin password there is a backdoor on your site or the server, or your password is something terrible like "password". You need someone knowledgeable to take a very close look.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the latest versions of Wordpress, plugins and themes.

Never use pirated/cracked/nulled plugins or themes as they often have backdoors.

Older themes had a bug related to Timthumb. Try [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/timthumb-vulnerability-scanner/) to check for the latest version (if you're using Timthumb).

You can also use a plugin like [this one](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/better-wp-security/) to get some more control over your website.

The problem may not come from WordPress itself, but it could also be that you've got a keylogger on your system. Read [Hardening WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress) to get a general idea about what you should do.

Answer (score 1):

Renaming the `index.php` wont really help much.

What you really need is something like "Better WP Security": http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/better-wp-security

> Better WP Security takes the best WordPress security features and
>   techniques and combines them in a single plugin thereby ensuring that
>   as many security holes as possible are patched without having to worry
>   about conflicting features or the possibility of missing anything on
>   your site.

It's the number 1 plugin for Wordpress security.